# How to take specific string in column mysql?

Tags: html, mysql

I have a table column that contain string like this :

```
<p><img alt="" src="http://www.kpu.go.id/application/modules/post/images/2d9af6bbca18d3faa06458a058df851d.jpg" style="height: 267px; width: 500px;" /></p>
```

I want to take just string in **src**, i mean url link of image. how to do this??

Comment: Are you asking how to pull out "src" with a MySQL query?

Comment: @h2ooooooo Yes, they want to get the content of src - which would be the URL.

Comment: yes, thats right. i wanna take that url.

Comment: @Jase I asked solely to confirm that this wasn't inside of PHP or with javascript, but he actually wanted it through the MySQL query. If you look at OPs other questions OP has a history of not tagging with the languages he's using.

Comment: This would be trivial with any standard language and you must be already using one because you have a database driven application. Why do it with SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this :

```
SUBSTR(column, LOCATE(column, 'src="'), LOCATE(column, '"', LOCATE(column, 'src="'))
```

That would get the substring starting with `src="` until the first `"` after that.

Answer (score 0):

You can **explode** this string using PHP's explode function by **"** delimiter.

```
$string = "<p><img alt=\"\" src=\"http://www.kpu.go.id/application/modules/post/images/2d9af6bbca18d3faa06458a058df851d.jpg\" style=\"height: 267px;  width: 500px;\" /></p>";

$array = explode('"', $string);
```

Then your image src will be a value of $array[3].

Comment: Strictly speaking, this is not SQL as requested.

Comment: @AlvaroGonzalez: true, I was just judging by the tags he used. PHP seems to be a natural friend for html and mysql.

Answer (score 0):

```
$html = '<p><img alt="" src="http://www.kpu.go.id/application/modules/post/images/2d9af6bbca18d3faa06458a058df851d.jpg" style="height: 267px; width: 500px;" /></p>';

preg_match( '@src="([^"]+)"@', $html, $match );

$src = array_pop($match);

echo $src;
```